# Error when computing geodesics in hyperbolic half plane

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

[It is known that the geodesic equations for the upper half plane equipped with the hyperbolic metric are](http://malkoun.org/RG/hyperbolic.pdf)

$$x''=\frac{2x'y'}{y},$$
$$y''=\frac{(y')^2 -(x')^2}{y}.$$

[It is also well known that the geodesics are semi-circles lying on the x-axis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model#Geodesics) However, I am encountering difficulties when I attempt to verify this fact.

> I am trying to follow the solution to part (b) of problem 5 on paper 1
>   [here.](http://www.math.harvard.edu/graduate/quals/qf13sol.pdf)

The path $\tilde \gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, when re-parameterized, should be a geodesic. At the point $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, the unit tangent vector is 
$$(-\sin^2(t), \sin(t)\cos(t)).$$
So we need
$$x''(t)=\frac{2(-\sin^2(t))(\sin(t)\cos(t)}{\sin(t)},$$
or $$x''(t)=-2\sin^2(t)\cos(t).$$
However, $(-\sin^2(t))'=-2\cos(t)\sin(t)$, which is not quite what we want. I'm confused why this does not line up. I suppose because the velocity field does not arise from a curve.

How can this be fixed up?

Comment: There's no reason that the semi-circle should be centered at $0$ which is what you're assuming when using your parametrization.

Comment: @Ahsan I'm not sure I understand your comment. Any semicircle, regardless of center, should be a geodesic. I chose to center mine at zero for convenience.

Comment: Ignore my comment. You are right in that an appropriate semicircle, regardless of the center should satisfy the equation. Answer upcoming in a bit.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1390602) below, a solution is given by $$(x(t), y(t)) = \left(  \dfrac{e^{2t} - 1}{e^{2t} + 1} , \dfrac{2e^t}{e^{2t} + 1}  \right), t \in \Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$ 0=E_1(E_j,E_k)= \frac{1}{y^2} \{ \Gamma_{1j}^k +
\Gamma_{1k}^j \} \Rightarrow \Gamma_{1j}^k =-\Gamma_{1k}^j  $$

$$ -2y^{-3}= E_2(E_2,E_2)= \frac{1}{y^2}
(2\Gamma_{22}^2) \Rightarrow \Gamma_{22}^2= - \frac{1}{y} $$

By definition,

$$ \Gamma_{12}^1 = -\frac{1}{y}$$

If $$ v= (-\sin^2 t, \sin\ t\cos\ t) :=fE_1+ g E_2$$ then $$ v (F(t))= y \frac{d}{dt} F(t) $$
and
$$
\nabla_vv = \nabla_v (fE_1) + \nabla_v (gE_2) $$ $$= v(f) E_1+
v(g)E_2 + f\nabla_vE_1 + g\nabla_vE_2 $$ $$ = y(f',g') + f ( f
\Gamma_{11}^i E_i + g \Gamma_{21}^i E_i) + g(  f \Gamma_{12}^i E_i +
g \Gamma_{22}^i E_i )
$$

$$ = y(f',g') + f^2 \Gamma_{11}^2E_2
+2f g \Gamma_{12}^1 E_1 + g^2  \Gamma_{22}^2 E_2 =0
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am having trouble understanding why this approach works and the one I sketched above doesn't. Shouldn't they be equivalent, as the geodesic equations are derived using the procedure you indicated?

Comment: You mean that you want to solve this problem by using $x'',\ y''$ instead of solution in link ?

Comment: Pardon my confusion, but isn't this approach the same thing as using $x''$ and $y''$? When you take take the covariant derivative of $v$, shouldn't $x''$ and $y''$ appear? (I agree this approach is best -- because it works! -- I just don't see why it's better.)

Comment: Note that geodesic equation in the first link is about curve of unit speed. So to apply geodesic equation we must find reparametrization $c(s) = (\cos\ f(s),\sin\ f(s)),\ t=f(s),\ |c'(s)|=1$, since $(\cos\ t,\sin\ t)$ do not have a unit speed. To find $f$, we solve $(f')^2=\sin^2 f$. I think that this is not easy.

Comment: Indeed. My question is: isn't the formula $\nabla_{v}v$ equivalent to the geodesic equation? Your computation looks very similar to mine, except you get a different term for $x''$ and $y''$. So if the ways are equivalent, why do they get different answers?

Comment: If $c(s)=(\cos\ f,\sin\ f)(s)$ and $|c'(s)|=1$, i.e., $\sin\ f=f'$, then it satisfies geodesic equation (x'=-\sin\ ff'=-\sin^2f,\ x''=-2\sin\ f\cos\ ff' you can check easily)

Comment: Great. Thank you. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't assume that the naive parametrization $(\text{cos}(t), \text{sin}(t))$ will solve the equation. It doesn't, as it clearly doesn't satisfy even the first differential equation. However, if you assume a more general form $x(t) = \text{cos}(f(t))$, $y(t)= \text{sin}(f(t))$, which still traces out a semicircle (but with a different speed), then it should be possible to find an $f(t)$ namely a reparametrization which makes the geodesic equations satisfied. If you plug in the above ansatz, both equations tell you that you need to solve $$f''(t) = \text{cot}(f(t)) (f'(t))^2,$$ which is solved by

$$f(t) = 2\text{cot}^{-1}(e^t)$$

Comment: Indeed, we know it exists, but the solution I'm reading seems to claim we can find it explicitly, or that something like what I mentioned above works. I added a link that may be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a careless error in deriving the differential equation. The correct form allows us to write an explicit solution. I've fixed this in the latest version.

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps elaborate on your first sentence? There's an ambiguity